# advice on sql Server db usage no arrays available?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following requirement and hope someone can provide a general guideline on how this can be done in SQL Server:

## Usage

1. Users sign up to the website
2. Then I match these users based on the their location. So two close users are matched together.
3. The number of matches is not clear, it could be 0 or 1000 user matches in one area

## Requirement

1. For each user, put all the matches in one record. Since SQL Server doesn't have concept of arrays how do I do this? Objects maybe?
2. Later in the site I need to sort the matches for a specific user based on time, distance etc.

Comment: Why do the matches need to go into one record? The natural thing in an RDBMS would to create another table that stores these. This would especially help since you'll need to sort on that data in another part of the app.

Comment: There is a separate table. How to handle a case where a 1000 users are all a match together? This would result in 1000 * 1000 = 1000 000 records!

Comment: Sql Server will handle a million records in a table w/o any problems. Wouldn't be much of a DB if it didn't. (Just remember to index the columns.)

Comment: Right, only an example to show that a 1000 users will yield 1000 000 records. What happens when there are 10 000 or 100 000 users, wouldn't the db crap out?

Answer (score 2):

**Your basic assumption is wrong!**

SQL does have arrays.  In fact **all**  SQL has is arrays; because a table is an array.

Let me explain.  An array is a sequence of values.  A table is also a sequence of values (and an order, if you have a column which provides sequence information.)

For your example lets say you have a user table.

```
UserID, UserName
```

In this table each row represents a single user.  You do not expect there to be two rows with the same userID

---

You can "associate" each user with an array of user by creating another table which is an array of users they are close to.

```
UserID, NearUserID, [Distance]
```

In this case this table would have multiple rows with the same UserID.  This creates your array.  If you want an ordering you can add a sequence or order column.

---

Here is what some SQL would look like to see each user and all their NearUsers:

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
JOIN NearUsers ON Users.UserID = NearUsers.NearUserID
```

Hope this helps.

---

Lets say you want to cut the records in half (see comment) with a table that matches users together in both directions

```
UserID1, UserID2
```

Then the SQL above can change to

```
SELECT Users.UserID, COALESCE(U1.UserID2,U2.UserID1) AS NearUser
FROM Users
JOIN UsersNear U1 ON Users.UserID = UserID1
JOIN UsersNear U2 ON Users.UserID = UserID2
```

This would be smaller (you are not storing an array for each user just the relationships) and more efficient than creating an array for each user.

Comment: Hi Hogan, Thanks for your answer. This is currently what I have. But imagine there are 1000 users and all of them are a match together. This would result in a new table of 1000*1000 = 1000 000 records!!! This is the problem I am trying to solve. Thanks again.

Comment: Still a table is the way to go -- name the table user1 and user2 then just write your code where you can join on the first user or the second.  Then you have half the records.  Don't worry about too many records in SQL.  Even 1000000 records is a small db.

Comment: please explain *"SQL does have arrays. In fact all SQL has is arrays; because a table is an array"* - Are you trying to illustrate a point, or are you trying to be technical, because underneath the bonnet, SQL is NOT an array.

Comment: From an abstract data type point of view (which I believe the OP referring to when he said SQL does not have arrays which I need to solve an algorithm), SQL does arrays -- an ordered collection of elements which can be selected by an index. In the context of any algorithm requiring arrays; SQL has arrays.  For the record, you did not mean "explain" you meant "defend."  I'm not trying to be technical or illustrate a point -- I'm trying to help the OP solve his problem (which clearly should be done with a table in SQL.)

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is real, then the only way to do it is to use a XML column containing all of the matches, or perhaps to have a comma-delimited  list of all of the matches.

You may want to find out why the requirement wants all of the matches in a single row. How will the callers use all of the matches that are in the one row?

Comment: Basically it is a user matching site (based on location). So every user has a list of matches. Anyway to do this using MS SQL? How does XML column in MS SQL work?   Thanks

Comment: An XML column is what it sounds like: one that can contain XML. Assuming that all you want is a match ID, you could return something like `<matches><match>1</match><match>2</match></matches>`.

Comment: Do you agree that this solution would take more storage space than a linking table?

Comment: @Hogan: probably, but he said everything has to be in a single row.

Answer (score 0):

What is your definition for 'close' users? Suburb, zip code, city????

1)If it is one of the above you are over complicating the whole thing, because all you will do then is to select all users where [zip,city,suburb,...] = 'X', then you can do exaclty what @Paul Sasik suggest and insert them into a seperate table, or just create a view or stored proc that will retrieve them for you when you need them

2)You almost need another table (or a rule) to define what closeness means in time, distance etc, and have a way to look it up and compare records. Once you can do that, you can create a user defined function that you can use in your queries.

@John S, I dont agree that XML is the 'only' way.

Comment: Thanks for youre answer. I actually match users based on geocode points. So every user will have a list of matches in a radius of x kilometers. Anyway to store the list of matches in some sort of an array?

Comment: When you start talking about arrays, CLR functions come to mind. If you have a method (rule) to determine the 'proximity', and you cannot find a way to do it in T-SQL, then you can always use a CLR function and do it in C#. Otherwise, (I have never worked with it), you can use the spacial column types in SQL Server and see if that will help you.